# hiera.yaml is not loading on vagrant provision

Tags: puppet, centos6, vagrant, provisioning, hiera

Whenever I provision vagrant all the data is nil. When I ssh in and specify `/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml` as the config option i can get the values. How can I get vagrant to use the right hiera.config file?

```
# Enable the Puppet provisioner
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/"
    puppet.manifest_file = "default.pp"
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.hiera_config_path = "puppet/hiera.yaml"
    puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
end
```

If you want to see all the code its on my bitbucket. https://bitbucket.org/yamiko/izanagi/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out hiera was being loaded but all the data was nil because one of my keys used invalid character for the parser. odd that it gave me nill instead of a parse error...

Answer (score 0):

hm, I dont see any fault in your config. 
but here's my working config:

```
node.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
  puppet.hiera_config_path = "puppet-data/hiera.yaml"
  puppet.manifests_path    = "puppet-data/"
  puppet.module_path       = "puppet-modules/modules"
  puppet.options           = "--parser future --verbose"
  puppet.facter = {
    "virtual_type" => "vagrant",
  }
```

hiera.yaml

```
:backends:
  - yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: '/vagrant/puppet-data'
:hierarchy:
  - common
```

puppet-data is a directory in the directory where the Vagrantfile is stored.